# Do bimetal jigsaw blades last twice as long as HSS blades and ten times longer than HCS blades?

Tags: engineering

Bosch makes this claim in their [jigsaw blade documentation](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1298/0900766b81298a05.pdf):

> Bi-Metal (BiM): This highly flexible, tough combination
>   of HSS [High-Speed Steel] and HCS [High-Carbon Steel] results in a blade
>   suitable for the most demanding
>   applications when there is a risk of
>   breakage or when extreme flexibility
>   and versatility are required.
>
> Ten times longer life than
>   standard HCS blade
>
> Two times longer life than
>   standard HSS blade

Is there some empirical evidence to back this up? Is it true independently of material being cut? I can see an HCS blade getting instantly ruined if one is trying to cut steel with it... but what about cutting hardwood or even softwood for instance? Do the multipliers still hold?

(They also make a claim about TC [tungsten carbide] blades lifetime but since those are uncommon [for jigsaws], I don't want to address that issue here.)